# How to use inheritance in JPA for returning class?

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

So here is what I basically want to do:

```
@Stateless
public abstract class GeneralDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Persistence")
    EntityManager em;

    private List<T> allT;

    public List<T> getAllT(){

        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery("Select t from T t",T.class);

    }

}
```

so for example I want to extend this class, say with an EmployeeDao like this:

```
 public class EmployeeDao extends GeneralDao<Employee>{

 }
```

And when I run:

```
employeeDao.getAllT()
```

I want to get a List. Well this does not work, because I guess Java does not like the T.class in getAllT method..

How can I generalize this? Any ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply allowing your subclasses to return the specific class type, like so:

```
public abstract class GeneralDao<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Persistence")
    EntityManager em;

    private List<T> allT;

    public List<T> getAllT(){

        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery("Select t from " + getClassType().getSimpleName() + " t", getClassType());

    }

    protected abstract Class<T> getClassType();
}
```

Comment: Does not work: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Select t from Actor], line 0, column -1: unexpected end of query.
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(-1!=80)

Comment: Thanks it worked like this: TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery("Select t from " + getClassType().getSimpleName() + " t", getClassType());

Comment: Sorry, I had updated on my editor by failed to update it on SO. My apologies. I fixed it now here.